# AWK: append number of lines *to next* occurance of pattern (in a huge file)

Tags: awk

Consider this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
TITLE something
some data
some data
some data
TITLE something else
some other data
TITLE some more
some other data
some other data
some other data
TITLE extra info
some more data
some more data
EOL
```

I need to add a new column that:

- counts the number of lines,
- goes back to 1 after an occurrence of `/^TITLE/`,
- starts from the bottom of the file and works its way upward,

Basically, the result should look like:

```
TITLE something,4
some data,3
some data,2
some data,1
TITLE something else,2
some other data,1
TITLE some more,4
some other data,3
some other data,2
some other data,1
TITLE extra info,3
some more data,2
some more data,1
```

P.S. you can assume that:

- the file always starts with a line matching `/^TITLE/`
- the file always ends with a line **not** matching `/^TITLE/`
- there are no two consecutive lines matching `/^TITLE/`

---

Edit:

Results so far

on a 100MB file:

@Yarom

```
time tac trial.txt | awk 'BEGIN{x=0} {x++;{if ($1 !~/^pattern/) printf "%s,%s\n",$0,x;else if ($1 ~/^pattern/) {printf "%s,%s\n",$0,x;x=0}}}' | tac > trial2.txt
real    0m0,896s
```

@bac0n

```
 time awk '{ a[i++]=$0 } END { while (i--) { a[i]=a[i] "," ++j; if (a[i] ~ /^pattern/) { j=0 } }; for (i=0; i<NR; i++) { print a[i] } }' trial.txt > trial2.txt
real    0m0,830s
```

@oliv:

```
time awk -v RS='^pattern' -v FS='\n' '
{
  for(i=NF-1;i>0;i--) 
    printf "%s,%d\n",$i,i; 
    printf RT
}' trial.txt > trial2.txt

real    0m2,343s
```

@steeldriver

```
 time awk -vRS='\n(^pattern|$)' -F'\n' -vOFS=, '
   NR>1 {$1 = "^pattern" $1} 
   {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i, NF-i+1}
 ' trial.txt > trial2.txt
real    0m1,889s
```

using mawk instead of awk, I get:

```
mawk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering but is there a chance you can also mark it as resolved? Thank you :)

Comment: It's not resolved. Reading your answer made me realize I need to edit the question a bit: you cannot assume that the non ```/^TITLE/``` lines start with DATA.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I changed it to `TITLE` and not `TITLE`, hoping it's better now :)

Comment: awk '{ a[i++]=$0 } END { while (i--) { a[i]=a[i] "," ++j; if (a[i] ~ /^TITLE/) { j=0 } }; for (i=0; i<NR; i++) { print a[i] } }' example_file.txt

Comment: oh! 10GB that will probably not work back to the drawingboard

Comment: nice but that should not be to hard to beat :)=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**example.awk**

```
#!/bin/awk -f

{ a[i++]=$0 } END {
    while (i--) {
        a[i]=a[i] "," ++j
        if (a[i] ~ /^TITLE/) { j=0 }
    }
    for (i in a) { print a[i] }
}
```

**Example**

```
awk -f example.awk example.txt
```

**Output**

```
TITLE something,4
DATA some data,3
DATA some data,2
DATA some data,1
TITLE something else,2
DATA some other data,1
TITLE some more,4
DATA some other data,3
DATA some other data,2
DATA some other data,1
TITLE extra info,3
DATA some more data,2
DATA some more data,1
```

Comment: Also does the job perfectly. I will leave the question open for a few hours to see if a faster answer pops up;)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to compile the following one-liner:

```
tac so_count.txt | awk 'BEGIN{x=0} {x++;{if ($1 != "TITLE") printf "%s,%s\n",$0,x;else if ($1 == "TITLE") {printf "%s,%s\n",$0,x;x=0}}}' | tac
```

I'll explain a bit further:

- `tac` - reverse the order of lines (reverse cat).
- `awk` - if the first column is not `TITLE` advance the counter, if `TITLE` print the current count and reset back to 0.
- `tac` - reverse it back.

Results:

```
TITLE something,4
DATA some data,3
DATA some data,2
DATA some data,1
TITLE something else,2
DATA some other data,1
TITLE some more,4
DATA some other data,3
DATA some other data,2
DATA some other data,1
TITLE extra info,3
DATA some more data,2
DATA some more data,1
```

Good luck!

Comment: your idea gives the desired result but it is very slow. The file is huge, > 10GB. I will leave the question open in the hope someone proposes a faster command.

Comment: OK, that will require actually counting and adding section by section, I can't think of a tool that can do it fast enough, what about splitting the file and running it in parallel on multiple smaller files? (Will probably require lots of RAM).

Comment: How about combining one of these solutions? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/how-can-i-print-lines-from-file-backwards-without-using-tac

Comment: yes, I'm looking at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112159/grep-from-the-end-of-a-file-to-the-beginning) too. Basically, I'm trying all these solutions. It's already good to know that I have yours in the bank in case these fail.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk -v RS='TITLE ' -v FS='\n' '
{
  for(i=NF-1;i>0;i--) 
    printf "%s,%d\n",$i,i; 
    printf RT
}' file
```

This relies on the record separator `RS` and the field separator `FS` that are set to set the right starting value to the counter `i`.

The only statements print each field with the counter and the record terminator `RT` associated to `RS`.

This solution has the advantage to only parse the file once and doesn't require to put the whole file in memory.

Comment: the real case counterpart to ```TITLE``` is ```|H|ENUM_SRC_ID|```, should I use ```\|H\|ENUM_SRC_ID\|```?

Comment: @user2413 as `|` is a keyword regex and awk treats backslash differently, you have to use 2 backslashes :  `-v RS='\\|H\\|ENUM_SRC_ID\\| '`

Answer (score 1):

You could treat each block as a record, and each line as a field - that way, you can get the per-block count down without either reversing the file or loading more than one block into memory.

Because your blocks are delineated by a header rather than a footer, a bit of hackery is required to handle the first an last records. The best I can come up with is:

```
awk -vRS='\n(TITLE|$)' -F'\n' -vOFS=, '
  NR>1 {$1 = "TITLE" $1} # replace the RS that got stripped off
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i, NF-i+1}
' example_file.txt
```

This should be valid in both `gawk` and `mawk`. I suspect it will run significantly faster in the lower-overhead `mawk`; `gawk` speed may be comparable if you set the locale to C/POSIX i.e. `LC_ALL=C awk '...'`

Comment: the real case counterpart to ```TITLE``` is ```|H|ENUM_SRC_ID|```, should I use ```\|H\|ENUM_SRC_ID\|```?

Comment: @user2413 you will need an extra backslash in the external `RS` regex assignment i.e. `-vRS='\n(\\|H\\|ENUM_SRC_ID\\||$)'` - the `$1` assignment requires no escaping (since it's just a string not a regex)